# How to get week number from date with Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

Anyone can show me how to get week number from a date uses Zend Framework 2? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the framework's featureset for this. Just the raw [language](http://php.net/date).

`date('W', $timestamp);`

> > `W`: ISO-8601 week number of year

*Note that `W` is uppercase. Lowecase `w` returns the day number of the week.*